# Improving a User Story with an [achievement] part the same as the [action] part

Tags: user-stories

Using this User Story definition:

> As an [actor], I want [action] so that [achievement]

focused on the value or result, I have my user story that reads:

> As a customer, I want to see nearby stores on the map so I see them on the map.

The problem is that the achievement part is the same as the action!

How can I improve this story?

Comment: your comment was helpful. I can update it to: so I can understand my surrounding. or anther one: as a customer I want to open the map and see nearby stores. if you mind post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classical User Story format is a way to express three different elements: the who, the what, and the why.

So to improve the your user story, you need to think about why a customer would care to see stores on the map. The purpose is obviously not just to see them on the map, the purpose is to do something with that information: go shopping, waste time while waiting to do something else, spend money on things that you need or bring joy, or whatever reason people have to go shopping. Just pick one that makes the most sense.

The important part here is not necessarily to write the perfect user story title, but to have the conversation about the "why". If you can't find a "why", the problem won't be that you can't improve the title of the user story, but the fact that you might build an useless feature that will go unused or brings no value to customers or to your business.

Note that you don't have to be a slave to this format and it's not mandatory to use. You are not breaking any Agile law by not respecting it. See more details on this post by Mike Cohn: [Why the Three-Part User Story Template Works So Well](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/why-the-three-part-user-story-template-works-so-well).

Comment: `why` clearly clarifies the intent. I should try to find answer for action: `as a customer I want see nearby stores on the map so I can make order from interested store.`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that the user's end goal is to see the store on a map; I would imagine that what the user actually wants is to visit the store ,or plan a route to the store, or select the closest store.

Just because I feel guilty about an answer without links, let me offer [value engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_engineering); that is my go to for understanding the theory behind the achievement part of the use case.